# Is there a way to make the comment module email the administrators when a comment needs approval?

Tags: 7, comments

I'd like to be notified whenever comments are made on the site which require administrator approval before publishing; basically, I'd like to know when something new appears in the Approval Queue. I can't see any obvious settings for this.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like something [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) should be able to do.

Comment: Is it possible to define a rule that will send a message only if the comment needs approval? in my case, some comments (e.g. by registered users) don't need approval.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Comment Mail](http://drupal.org/project/commentmail) module -- if you're going to get an email each time there is a comment you might as well simplify the process by adding approval functionality:

> The Comment Mail module allows an email to be sent to the site
>   administrator(s) when new comments are posted. A link in the email
>   allows quick approval, editing, deletion, and/or banning of the
>   poster's IP address.

Word of caution: I've used this method before but quickly turned it off after the spam comments broke my spirit. Make sure you've got a robust anti-spam strategy setup (ex. antispam, mollom, captcha/recaptcha, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes; "rules" in your Drupal is the way to go: easiest and fastest.