# In a message about a new comment, how to tell if the comment needs approval or not?

Tags: 7, comments, emails

I am currently using Triggers + Actions to send the node author an email when a new comment is added.

Some of the commentators on my site do not require approval (registered users and [repeat commentators](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/how-to-approve-comments-from-a-user-with-previously-approved-comments/12325#12325)).

I would like to indicate in the mail whether the comment requires approval - or send a different message all together in this case. I didn't find any way to configure this.

Answers to a [related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2048/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-comment-module-email-the-administrators-when-a-comment) suggested the Rules module, but I didn't find a way to make a condition based on whether the comment needs approval.

Edit: I think that the relevant conditions is about comment:status. This field doesn't appear as a data selector in Rules, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great [tutorial](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/996) on [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) with a similar use case.